# Javascript passing data between text boxes

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I'm working on getting data to go from one textbox to another using javascript. Im new to Javascript and im getting a document undefined or null error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function doit() {
        window.document.form1.txtbox1.value= window.document.form2.txtbox2.value;
      }
   </script>
  </head>
 <body>

   <form name="form1">
     Enter your name:
     <input type="text" name="txtbox1" value="">
     <input type="button" name="btn1" value="Click" onclick="doit()">
   </form>

   <br><br><br>
   <form name="form2">
     Results: 
     <input type="text" name="txtbox2" value="">
   </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you go to learn [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) first.  We select tags like this `document.getElementsByTagName("form");` and by class name `document.getElementsByClassName("the-class");` or even by ID `document.getElementById("the-id");` or by name `document.getElementsByName("form1");`. And there are many other ways. Welcome Mike

Comment: How are you getting `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: Please explain the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying access the element as a property of the DOM.

Instead, you should use `document.getElementsByName` method.

Revised function:

```
function doit(){
// The [0] is for accessing the first item.
// If you are unfamiliar with arrays, visit
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
  document.getElementsByName("txtbox1")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("txtbox2")[0].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch (swap) them :
  `window.document.form1.txtbox1.value= window.document.form2.txtbox2.value;`

When you click a button - you set the value of the second input to the first one and probably the second input called 'Result' is empty.

Try:

```
      function doit() {
        window.document.form2.txtbox2.value = window.document.form1.txtbox1.value;
      }
```

There should not be any error, it's just pass data in another direction as you probably expect.

Answer (score 0):

Give a unique ID to both the input element.

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox1" value="">
<input type="text" id="txtbox2" value="">
```

and in function doit()

```
document.getElementById("txtbox2").value = document.getElementById("txtbox1").value
```